# Phonegap WatchPosition stops updating. EBUSY?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

i have a phonegap project that uses WatchPosition in background of the app. It works sometime but sometimes when the app starts i get Location Timeout error 3.

And the log for my iPhone says that the location is (EBUSY).

Is this a phonegap bug?

Code:

```
  function onDeviceReady() {
                    var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { timeout: 10000, frequency: 3000,enableHighAccuracy: true });
                }
function onSuccess(position) {
            var deviceID = device.uuid;
            $.post("http://server.com/project/savelocation.php", { lat: position.coords.longitude, lng: position.coords.latitude, device: deviceID },
               function(data) {
               console.log("Location updated.");
               });
               }
```

It does work sometimes as i said, but the errors i get are :

```
[INFO] code: 3
    message: Geolocation Error: Timeout.

locationd[41] <Notice>: received EBUSY, try kScanTypeChannel, channel, 11, rssi -60, delayed 0.000s
```

Can this be iOS 6 errors?

I also have Phonegap 1.2.0 so i dont use the latest Cordova project yet.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i needed to upgrade to latest Cordova. iOS 6 support was horrible on Phonegap 1.2.0!